# Is there an equivalent of VB's VBC_VER for c# compilation?

Tags: c#, conditional-compilation

For [a while now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swfss70d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the `VBC_VER` constant was defined such that you could do things like:

```
#If VBC_VER >= 9.0 Then
Imports System.Net.Mail
#Else
Imports System.Web.Mail
#End If
```

Is there an equivalent that can be used in C# code, or a comparison of those constants defined automatically?

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I'm aware of. You can define your own preprocessor symbols in a project file, of course.

Bear in mind that "version of C#" and "version of .NET that the project is targeting" are not the same thing, either. I would expect which *namespaces* you want to use to depend more on the framework version you're using than the language version.

Comment: My use case this time around is for a nice handy constant for async support. I did see that you can [define constants based on the version of the framework being targetted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7888576/50447), but these don't appear to be able to set a version in the same manner as the old VBC_VER. Looks like my project is about to grow some additional configurations...