# VS Installer copy different files per installer compilation

Tags: c#, installation, vsinstaller

I have a VS installer copying several files.
I need to maintain 2 differnt installers 1 with specific files included and the other without.
I want to use the same installer project.
I thought maybe this can be done - getting the differnt result according to some define parameter 
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do so.
using the MSBuild conditional dependencies and then using the output of some project.
[MS Build conditional referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-sharp-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can do this by putting code into the Pre-build and Post-build events of the installer project.

Use a compiler directive for each of the builds and then you put DOS command line stuff into the pre/post build event command line box depending on what you need to do.  Then you just perform 2 builds with 2 difference compiler directives.

It's actually pretty simple, a simple copy of a file would be like:

copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)lib\$(ProjectName).dll"

Obviously, you would probably have more stuff than this in there but you get the picture.  They're basic DOS batch file commands.