# Prevent .NET version change

Tags: c#, .net

So I have a project inside a huge solution.

My project is .NET 3.5 and the rest of the solution is 4.7.1. 
My goal is that if someone else tries to update my project from 3.5 it will fail to compile.

tl;dr

1. How do I read the .net version of a project?
2. How do I conditionally fail a compilation?

Comment: *Why* would you want to do this? You could use conditional compilation though

Comment: If they are updating the framework version then there's probably nothing you can do in code that they couldn't override/delete anyway

Comment: You'd rather devote an unknown amount of time to *preventing someone from performing what will, in time, be inevitably required*, rather than spend an unknown amount of time fixing whatever issues currently mean that the project shouldn't be upgraded?

Comment: no choice in the matter, its a dll that interacts with  3rd party software that i have no control over.
medical imaging is fun!

also, i don't understand why the duplication since i clearly didn't know about  conditional compilation for .NET versions but i got my answer so yay

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional compilation like this

```
#if !NET35
#error This project requires .NET 3.5 framework
#endif
```

Comment: You mean "[Conditional Compilation and Framework Targets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2923210/107625)".

Comment: Odd, I read that as `#error Delete this line if you want to compile`